# Need to do ssh to Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to take ssh to pod?
Eg: `ssh pod_ip`

I know we can do this with the `kubectl` command. But I need to do `ssh` from my local linux machine which doesn't have `kubectl`.

Comment: Would you mind providing some context on why you need to ssh? And why is kubectl not installed?

Answer (score 82):

Firstly, you have to ensure that the openssh-server has been installed and running in the pod. If not, you can use `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -n <namespace> -- bash` to access the pod. 
If your pod are running Ubuntu, do `apt-get install -y openssh-server`.

Secondly, pods are running in a virtual IP subnet assigned by network service. They are accessible to any Master nodes and Worker nodes in the cluster. You can do ssh from any of the Host OS.

Comment: The `-n <namespace>` is critical if you are getting `No resources found in default namespace.` when you run `kubectl get pods`

Comment: `bash` could be `/bin/bash/` or `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 79):

If you would like to login inside a particular container in the POD

**`kubectl exec -it <Pod_Name> -c <Container_Name> -- /bin/bash`**

If you would like to login to default container (or if there is only one container in POD) then just use

`kubectl exec -it <Pod_Name>  -- /bin/bash`

PS:-   If  **/bin/bash** is not working try **/bin/sh**

Comment: the OP asked for an answer without kubectl.

Comment: Can I run `kubectl exec -it deployments/{deployment_name} bash`?

Comment: I guess not, generally you exec to a POD not the deployment. Deployment can have so many pods, and so you need to decide you pod want to login!

Comment: @ErezHochman this is still a useful answer for people who arrive at this question but do have `kubectl`

Answer (score 5):

for anyone looking for a one liner, this should do it.

Given:

- **namespace**: cars
- **app**: hud

Running, gets you bash in the first pod:

```
kubectl exec -i -t $(kubectl get pod --namespace cars --selector='app=hud' --output jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -n cars -- /bin/bash
```

Where this extracts the 1st pod when listing pods:

```
$(kubectl get pod --namespace cars --selector='app=hud' --output jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try, OpenPubkey to SSH Without SSH Keys.
Following are the links for more information.

- https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-openpubkey-to-ssh-without-ssh-keys/
- https://www.bastionzero.com/blog/why-you-should-use-bastionzero-to-secure-access-to-your-k8s-clusters?utm_content=248533620&utm_medium=social&utm_source=linkedin&hss_channel=lcp-71618213

Answer (score -2):

I use:

```
kubectl exec -it deployments.apps/deployment-example bash -n namespace-example
```