# How can I SSH to my GCP Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-kubernetes-engine

I created cluster in dashboard. From cloudshell,.ssh folder

```
jhomes369@cloudshell:~/.ssh (leafy-garden-359409)$ ls -la
total 20
drwx------ 2 jhomes369 jhomes369 4096 Oct  4 11:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 jhomes369 jhomes369 4096 Oct  3 10:11 ..
-rw------- 1 jhomes369 jhomes369    0 Oct  4 11:00 admin-cluster.key
-rw------- 1 jhomes369 jhomes369 2643 Sep 20 10:18 google_compute_engine
-rw-r--r-- 1 jhomes369 jhomes369  597 Sep 20 10:18 google_compute_engine.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 jhomes369 jhomes369  189 Sep 20 10:18 google_compute_known_hosts
-rw------- 1 jhomes369 jhomes369    0 Oct  4 10:55 mgmt-cluster-2.key
```

How to connect to GKE cluster from me Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714658/need-to-do-ssh-to-kubernetes-pod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to the `GKE` cluster from your `Ubuntu` and local machine with a `gcloud` command :

```bash
gcloud container clusters get-credentials your-gke --region europe-west1 --project your-project
```

You need to use an authorized `identity` from you `shell` session (Google user or Service Account).

Comment: Once you've got the credentials you still need to use `kubectl` to login - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714658/need-to-do-ssh-to-kubernetes-pod